# How to allocate texts on the even page, and figures and tables on the odd pages?

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, xelatex

For a report, I've to write one page on two of text, the other being for the figures and tables. I mean, I have to write on the even pages the text and on the odd pages the graphics, figures, tables.

I couldn't find what I should do to produce PDF with `Rmarkdown` via `XeLaTeX` on the web. Is there any particular script for this?

Thanks !

Comment: it's not quite clear what you mean with "one page on two", please also show what you tried. Probably this question is a better fit for https://tex.stackexchange.com/ anyway.

Comment: I have to write on the even pages the text and on the odd pages the graphics, figures, tables

I will check on tex.stackexchange.com !

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode you can press alt and select another place to type. I do not know in other editors.